# How can we change the color of placeholder?

Tags: css

How can we change the color of placeholder of selected input fields.

```
input[type="text"].smInput{
color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2610497/1492578)

Comment: Please use google like this before asking question `site:stackoverflow.com How can we change the color of placeholder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input[type="text"].smInput:-moz-placeholder, textarea:-moz-placeholder{
    color: #222;
}
input[type="text"].smInput::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea::-moz-placeholder{
    color: #222;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder text is exposed to CSS as a pseudo-element, so use the pseudo-element selector. It hasn't yet been standardised, so you need to repeat the selector for the layout-engines that support it:

```
input[type=text].smInput::-moz-placeholder,
input[type=text].smInput:-ms-input-placeholder, /* IE uses a pseudo-class rather than pseudo-element */
input[type=text].smInput::-webkit-input-placeholder, {
    color: #333;
}
```

Source:

- [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a-moz-placeholder)
- [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3a-moz-placeholder)
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772745(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
input:-moz-placeholder, textarea:-moz-placeholder{
    color: #222;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea::-moz-placeholder{
    color: #222;
}
```